# Receiving MATLAB Error Regarding Function Arguments

Tags: matlab, analysis, spectral

When running my MATLAB script below, I keep getting an error that states:

1. Error using **spa** (Line 147)  
   The value of the window
   size must be an integer greater than 2.
2. Error in "projectName"   G = spa(xFunction2, x)

I've tried putting in multiple types of arguments into "spa" (data, windowsize, frequency) but it still yields the same error(s). Help?

```
n = 1:1024; 

%Signal Function 
xFunction = sqrt(10)*exp(j*2*pi*0.10*n)+ sqrt(20)*exp(j*2*pi*0.20*n) + sqrt(625); 

%Complex Noise Function
zFunction = 0.707*randn(size(n)) + j*0.707*randn(size(n));

%Computing the value of x(n) + sqrt(625)*z
xFunction2 = xFunction + sqrt(625)*zFunction;  

G = spa(xFunction2,51);
figure(1); 
plot(w, 10*log10(G));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording the documentation of [spa](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/spa.html) the first argument is `iddata` type. In addition, the time serie has to be a column vector.
So, to make it works change `G = spa(xFunction2,51);` for `G = spa(xFunction2(:),51);`. To do it the correct way, convert your time serie to `iddata`:

```
Ts = 0.1;          % what ever is your sampling time.
myiddata = iddata(xFunction2(:),[],Ts);

G = spa(myiddata,51);
```

In addition, you should use `spectrum(G)` or `bode(G)`to plot the result.

Comment: Though I have done some work in MATLAB previously, I did not even know of the "iddata" type and that the time series must be a column vector for spa to work. 

Thank you so very much for your help Seba! I appreciate it greatly.